# "Savings Account" vs "Checkings Account"

Tags: grammar

The correct form is "savings account". Why don't we say "checkings account"? Why is "checkings account" incorrect and why is "savings account" correct? We certainly wouldn't say "saving account". Please advise.

Comment: In Britain we have never said 'checkings account'. In any event we spell them as: 'cheques'. That type of account we call a 'current account', and the other type either a 'deposit account' or a 'savings account'. It used to be the case that current accounts did not carry interest, but some now do, I believe.

Comment: This is largely addressed in the thread 'Why does American English pluralize certain singular nouns?' The noun 'savings' in its non-count form is given plural concord in BrE ('Check your savings are FSCS protected here.' – internet). But as tdhsmith says at the former thread, 'The plural may be used to emphasise the plurality of the attribute, especially in British English but very rarely in American English: a careers advisor, a languages expert.' So, in the US, 'savings' is possibly being classed as a noun taking singular agreement to fit in. Thus 'I have a savings of $100 in the bank.'

Answer (score 7):

"Savings" is what is in the Savings Account.

Drawing checks against your account, or "Checking" is what you do with the Checking Account.

There isn't an analogy between the two names to force a similar name scheme.

Comment: Good answer. Would be even better if you linked to a definition of _savings_ that shows how it's not a simple gerund or participle.